# R-Markdown: Serifless font

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using the following markdown header. Unfortunately the font in my pdf still has serifes. How can I change that globally? (I've tried `\usepackage{uarial}` as well as `mainfont: Arial`)

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
- \usepackage{uarial}
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
mainfont: Arial
fontsize: 13pt
documentclass: article
---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try renew the command `\familydefault`.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
- \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: yes
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
mainfont: Arial
fontsize: 13pt
documentclass: article
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

[image]